# how can create the optimal design for convolutional neural network

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

is there any rule to choose the number of layers in convolutional neural network or it's just as try and error ? so if we have an input image of size 256 x 256 how can we create an best mode, how many conv layer, max pool, FC, the filter sizes and learning rate. Also how can we know the optimal number of epochs for training the dataset. Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

There has been a good discussion of this topic on stats.stackexchange:

[How to choose the number of hidden layers and nodes in a feedforward neural network?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181/how-to-choose-the-number-of-hidden-layers-and-nodes-in-a-feedforward-neural-netw)

Otherwise, there is no straight and easy answer to this. I can only suggest to dive into scientific literature:

https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=optimal+size+of+neural+network&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_vis=1